# Loading external SWF into AIR Application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash, external, jwplayer

I'm trying to load external SWF (**JW Player**) into my AIR Application using **loadBytes**. I'm using the following code:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public function Invoker()
{
trace("INIT");
var uldr : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
uldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
uldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onBytesComplete);
uldr.load(new URLRequest("Resources/5.1.swf"));
}

private function onBytesComplete(e : Event) : void
{
trace("LOADED");
var bytes : ByteArray = (e.target as URLLoader).data;
var ldr : Loader = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChildComplete);
var ldrC : LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
ldrC.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;
ldr.loadBytes(bytes, ldrC);

}

private function onChildComplete(e : Event):void
{
trace("COMPLETE");
var c1ad : ApplicationDomain = (e.target as LoaderInfo).applicationDomain;
var inad : ApplicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
trace(c1ad);
trace(inad);
}
```

But, when I put

**uic.addChild(ldr);**
or
**canv.addChild(ldr);** (uic is **mx:UIComponent** and canv is **mx:Canvas**)
into the **onBytesComplete** function, I get the following error:

```
SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.
    at flash.system::Security$/allowDomain()
    at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.media::YouTubeMediaProvider/initializeMediaProvider()
    at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.model::Model/setMediaProvider()
    at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.model::Model/setupMediaProviders()
    at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.controller::PlayerSetup/setupMediaProviders()
    at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.controller::TaskQueue/nextTask()
    at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.controller::TaskQueue/success()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.view.skins::DefaultSkin/loadComplete()
```

Idea? Please Help!

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I changed a few functions in the JW Player source classes.

In the *com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/YouTubeMediaProvider.as* in the function **initializeMediaProvider(**) added **Security.allowDomain("*");**

In the *com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/model/Model.as* in the function **setupMediaProviders()** commented the rows: **setMediaProvider('default', new MediaProvider('default'));** and  **setMediaProvider('youtube', new YouTubeMediaProvider());**

I'm not using youtube, so it works fine!

Hope this helps!